# Loading until datas are available

Tags: android, download

I'm making an application, which only pick some datas on a website. But the problem is that the layout does not show up until the datas are available, the application seem to be blocked while it is looking for the datas. I tried to put the content view in the oncreate and then change the text in the onstart, when I have the datas, but the application still blocks.

Is this possible to print a default text, and then change it when the application have the datas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it uses `AsyncTask`:

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //declare other objects as per your need
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        //show loading dialog
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);

        //do initialization of required objects objects here                
    };      
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {   

         //do loading operation here  
        return null;
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    };
 }
```

You can call this using from your `onCreate()`:

```
LoadData task = new LoadData();
task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AsyncTask to download data from website (API)? It will show you progressdialog until data is not downloaded.